# document.write('<div id="container"') issues in IE7 it closes automatically

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, document

hi i am creating one div in inline Javascript...its closing immidiately in IE7 only remaining browsers will close the tag when we write document.write('')...

```
document.write('<div id="container" style="position:relative;width:234px;height:160px;overflow:hidden;border:0px;">')
```

Comment: `document.write()` is not a good way to manipulate the DOM because it's a blocking function that will stop the page load until this complete. Try appending the item to an existing DIV or to the body.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dynamicDiv = document.createElement("div");
dynamicDiv.id = "container";
dynamicDiv.style.position = "relative";
dynamicDiv.style.width = "234px";
dynamicDiv.style.height = "160px";
dynamicDiv.style.overflow = "hidden";
dynamicDiv.style.border = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(dynamicDiv);
```

Thats how I perform DOM mutation.

Comment: This is much better than using document.write because your browser doesn't have to guess at what you are trying to do.

Comment: hi inbetween div open and close tag i need to generate some content logically so explicity i need to close the tag whenever i need so the above logic is not suitable for me ...
document.write('<div id="container" style="position:relative;width:234px;height:160px;overflow:hidden;border:0px;">')
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>ONE</td>
    <td>TWO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
document.write('</div>') now i am closin this div tag its working fine in rest of the browsers..only in IE6&IE7 its not workin

Comment: @kumarjcet it can still work.  If you were to do it this way it would be a pain to do it with only DOM node insertion, but instead you might try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3YFh/. also... is the table dynamically inserted too or is it just there and you're trying to wrap it with a div?

Comment: hi innerhtml content are dynamic so cant write like that

Comment: <div id="container" style="position:relative;width:250px;height:165px;overflow:hidden;border:0px;">
<div id="content" style="position:absolute;width:250px;left:0px;top:-1px;border:0px;">
getting issue here ony because of position only in IE6 & IE7